# IOS: Good way to add XMP metadata to AAC encoded m4a file?

Tags: ios, audio, metadata, xmp

I'm creating an AAC encoded m4a file from raw PCM samples for streaming purposes. I'm using AAC hardware encoding provided in this example.  [iPhoneExtAudioFileConvertTest](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/iPhoneExtAudioFileConvertTest/Introduction/Intro.html)

Now I would really want to add metadata such as album artwork and titles.
As I understand m4a or mp4 containers are MPEG-4 Part 14. So the specified metadata format is XMP. However I do not know the good tool for working with XMP metadata. Any ideas?

I'm aware of Adobe XMP SDK, but it seems quite heavyweight, maybe there is a better solution for iOS. I mean, I doubt that it's possible to do in AVFoundation, as XMP is Adobe technology, but maybe someone wrote a nice library especially for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know in what terms you think XMP SDK to be a heavyweight.But I can assure you that it hardly takes 15 mins to download, compile and start using the SDK.
You could start by editing one of the Samples(Modify) that come with XMP SDK and then use the snippet inside your application.